# Multiple MQ listeners

Tags: listener, mq

I have a scenario where we have two MQ listeners in our application. One of them is doing some added processing(database tables update), day queue A and the other one is not, say queue B. The issue is we just have one thread(the main thread for both of these) and message is sent to the A first. So by the time the code reaches the point where it’s going to process/update message received on A, message on B arrives and hence the update never goes through. How can I make sure that the processing occurs for messages on A even while B received messages?

Thanks

Comment: Setup two message listeners, one for each queue. That will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you **must** use one thread to process all messages you should use synchronous api calls like this:

```
long timeoutForA, timeoutForB ...
MessageConsumer consumerA, consumerB ....

while (true) {
  Message msgFromA = consumerA.receive(timeout);
  if (msgFromA == null) 
    break;
  ... do something with message from A ...
}

while (true) {
  Message msgFromB = consumerB.receive(timeout);
  if (msgFromB == null) 
    break;
  ... do something with message from B ...
}
```

However I would not recommend this approach to business logic as in general. Properly designed messaging system should be able process unrelated messages asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on language that you use.

If you use C you can try to use callbacks.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023050_.htm